# How to restart Activity and save all previously opened activities in Android SDK < 11

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I need to restart my PreferenceActivity and save all previously opened Activities. I can easy do this in Android SDK >11 only with one line of the code **super.recreate();** In this case my Activity is restarted and all previous Activities are also in back stack and when I press the Back button, I get previous Activity. But this wonderful method is available only for devices with Android ver 11 and greater. But what about Android versions lower than 11? In this case I am doing this: **finish(); startActivity(getIntent());**

Everything is OK, but when I am pressing the Back button, the current Activity finishes its work and closes and thats all and  I dont getting previously opened Activity. Does anyone have ideas how to solve this problem?

This is my code

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            super.recreate();
        } 
 else {
      finish();
      startActivity(getIntent());
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is start the PreferenceActivity with `Activity.startActivityForResult()` and when you need to recreate your activity, just finish with using the `Activity.RESULT_FAILED` constant to indicate that the activity wishes to be recreated. This way, you will maintain your state going in, and if you need to pass data back, just set your result intent.

Comment: So, the sceme is next: 1. In my Activity "A" I call startActivityForResult(PreferenceActivity). 2. Then in PreferenceActivity I am finishing  it with the result code Activity.RESULT_FAILED. 3. The in Activity "A" in onActivityResult method I am getting Activity.RESULT_FAILED code and startinf PreferenceActivity again?

Comment: Absolutely :) That is how I would do it.

Comment: That's great solution! Thank you very much! And I also want to ask, may be there is an easy way how to do this in case when I can start PreferenceActivity from many other Activities, or I need to implement this algorithm in every activity which can launch PreferenceActivity?

Comment: Well, if you are using my solution, then really the only way is to write a base class with method to launch the preference activity.